# Regular expression -- ignore part of a matched string

Tags: java, regex

I have text that I want to fined some thing like this

```
 "Name DAVID"
```

I want to match "DAVID" in this, larger, text.
I tried use a regular expression like this:

```
 (Name(.*))
```

and also

```
 (?:Name(.*))
```

but this also matched "Name," and I only want to match "David".

Comment: You should add the code that you use to run that regex too, the regex are fine (the 1st one at least, I haven't tested the second one), it depends on how you use them

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the extra parens:

```
"Name (.*)"
```

Even that is probably excessive, you probably want something more like:

```
"Name (\w*)"
```

to catch exactly the characters that you want.

Comment: I dont understand "Name (.*)"
gives me "Name DAVID"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `Matcher`. This snippet of code worked for me

```
public static void main(String[] asdf) {
           String text = "NAME David";
           Pattern p = Pattern.compile("NAME (.+)");
           Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
           if (m.matches()){
               System.out.println(m.group(1));
           }
    }
```

Note that `m.matches()` is mandatory or `m.group(1)` will throw `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found`

Comment: I know this solution but I belive that their is a better way to do this. why I need to catch things that I dont need?

Comment: What do you mean by `why I need to catch things that I dont need?`? You don't have to catch any exception, the exception is thrown always if you don't invoke `matches()` before `group()`, regardless if there is a match or not

Comment: If you knew this solution, why didn't you say so in the question? Now a lot of people repeated it.

Answer (score 0):

String's `matches()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String regex = "^Name(.+)$";
    System.out.println("Name".matches(regex));
    System.out.println("Name MIKE".matches(regex));
    System.out.println("Name DAVID".matches(regex));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it doesn't look like your question had yet been answered with a correct regex for what you requested.

Here is what you are looking for:

```
(?<=Name )DAVID
```

This only matches `DAVID`, in the proper context (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/nJ3bU7)).

You probably know this, but this is a way to test a string with this regex:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=Name )DAVID");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
foundMatch = regexMatcher.find();
```

**Explain Regex**

```
(?<=                     # look behind to see if there is:
  Name                   #   'Name '
)                        # end of look-behind
DAVID                    # 'DAVID'
```